# SSRS Using some Field Values from Dataset1 as Parameters in DataSet2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2016

I have a dataset referring to a stored procedure which delivers me some data.
One column contains a specific Code (see picture), which I want to use in the second table/dataset.
For each of the Codes (amount is variable) I want to add a new table with the details of that code.

The second dataset also feeds a stored procedure.
Both procedures can´t be touched, because they are used in many other applications.

how to realize?

[image: see the relationship]

I tried to use the "lookupset" function in SSRS after searching the web for a solution. I got different problems / errors. Sometimes no parameters specified, sometimes field value cant be used as a parameter.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a new dataset that just gets the code from your stored proc (it will run the SP again but not too much can be done about that).

Here's a simplified example..

Let's say you SP only return 3 columns ( MaterialNo, MaterialName and Code)

You can create a temp table to put the results into and then query the temp table so your dataset query would look something like this..

```
CREATE TABLE #t(MaterialNo int, MaterialName varchar(50), Code varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #t 
    EXEC myProcName
--
SELECT d.*
    FROM myDetailsTable d
    JOIN #t t on d.Code = t.Code
```

Now you have the data you need you can create a table, grouped by code and add whatever details in you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution here is to use a [Subreport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/subreports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16)

> A subreport is a report item that displays another report inside the body of a main paginated report. Conceptually, a subreport in a report is similar to a frame in a Web page. It is used to embed a report within a report. Any report can be used as a subreport. The report that is displayed as the subreport is stored on a report server, usually in the same folder as the parent report. You can design the parent report to pass parameters to the subreport. **A subreport can be repeated within data regions, using a parameter to filter data in each instance of the subreport.**

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But how do I get the LotCodes from the first dataset to the parameters in the second, third, fouth dataset?

Comment: Passing parameters to subreports is covered here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/subreports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16#using-parameters-in-subreports  Also plenty of videos and tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks, but all the hints I found only describe how to add a subreport inside the main report with relations to the explicit fields. None of these describes how to extract some of the field values to use them in a seperate table.

Comment: The subreport has it's own data sources and datasets.  You just pass parameters to the subreport from the main report.

Comment: Yes, I see. But when I use the subreport inside the main report, I can just take Field result by using the column name. There is no need to write a fuction or something. When using the Field result in a seperate table I can´t access it in the same way..

Comment: My Question is how to access these values?